# nasm: relocation truncated to fit: R_386_PC8 against `*UND*'

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I get the following error when linking the code below, but I don't understand why:

```
ld -m elf_i386 shell.o -o test
shell.o: In function `_start':
shell.asm:(.text+0xbc): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_PC8 against `*UND*'
```

Code:

```
SECTION .text
global      _start                              ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:
 xor    eax,eax
 push   eax
 push   0x25722424
 push   0x73747670
          push   0x24777470
       push   0x75792278
       push   0x27757070
          push   0x23732473
          push   0x70277275
         push   0x22247975
          push   0x27237824
       push   0x20722774
     push   0x24257674
push   0x79237524
 push   0x24752377
       push   0x22727925
         push   0x27772020
          push   0x71792771
    push   0x72257073
         push   0x78237173
         push   0x71767975
          push   0x73717871
  push   0x20727827
         push   0x27782272
        push   0x74797423
       push   0x25742271
        push   0x72772225
          push   0x70247024
          push   0x72727023
       push   0x24782078
          push   0x71742023
          push   0x71242379
         push   0x22787024
          push   0x24782374
  push   esp
 pop    esi
                  mov    edi,esi
                mov    edx,edi
                cld
      mov    ecx,0x80
          mov    ebx,0x41
                 xor    eax,eax
                   push   eax
                  lodsb
                   xor    eax,ebx
                   stosb
                loop   0xb7
                  push   esp
                    pop    esi
int3
```

Comment: Modify `loop   0xb7` to use a label and not an immediate value.

Comment: also, try harder ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
push eax
michael:
lodsb
xor eax,ebx
stosb
loop michael
push esp
pop esi
int3
```

Just use a label for the loop like I did in the previous code. I called it michael but remember you have to define it first like this michael: and then you can use it.